405 (Method Not Allowed) Error in Vercel FastAPI Backend (But Works Locally)
I have just deployed my NextJS-frontend/FastAPI-backend app on Vercel, and I am currently running into an issue that seems related to CORS that is giving me a 405 Method Not Allowed when I try to POST/GET to my FastAPI backend from the frontend.
For context, this works in my local development environment where the frontend is located in localhost:3000, and the backend is localhost:8000
Below is the attached image of the error.

I have tried a few things, this is my next.config.js at the root of my directory
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  rewrites: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:path*",
        destination:
          process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
            ? {NEXT_PUBLIC_LOCALHOST_URL} + "/:path*"
            : "/",
      }
    ];
  },
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // matching all API routes
        source: "/:path*",
        headers: [
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "*" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "*" },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = nextConfig;

Then in my main.py which is the entry point to my FastAPI backend, I have the following policies:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from api.v1.endpoints import text, image, video, index

app = FastAPI()

# Add CORS middleware
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
    expose_headers=["*"]
)

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Welcome to the API!"}

app.include_router(text.router)
app.include_router(image.router)
app.include_router(video.router)
app.include_router(index.router)

Interestingly enough, if I try to use cURL and send a POST/GET request to the endpoints, I get nothing in return.

This and this might help.

Wildcards doesn't work with allow_credentials=True in FastAPI's CORSMiddleware.
You should specify allowed origins explicitly
